# If website gets closed return og kill session

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

i got a tiny issue.

On my webpage i have a system that check how many users that is online and display their username. The code counts from table. When they login it gets inserted to database, and when they logout it delete. If they are inactive for 15 minutes, they get redirected to logout page.

**BUT**

If the user just close the page or computer is shutdowned the logout og unactive code cant read that, so that means the user never gets deleted from tabel and therfore are online until next time they login and OUT.

This is not the biggest issu or most importen, bu i really wan to fix it.

**Some suggestions?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store in that table the last activity time and update it every time a user makes some action on the site.

Delete anyone who is inactive for more than 15 minutes.

Comment: You got an example code? :) I know how to "SELECT * FROM user_inactive where Last_activity > timestampadd(minutes, -15, now())" but i maby need an if statement?